# Auto discovery of HPC Headnodes/Brokernodes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hpc

I would like to make a drop down on a UI component for my users to select the Headnode/Brokernode that they want to submit their job to. I would like to populate this dropdown with the heads/brokers on the network.

Taking this further it would also be good to provide some feedback as to what SOA services are available on the selected node.

Any ideas or suggestions for a neat way to do this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

-Edit-
You can use active directory as this Microsoft example shows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907077(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Edit- You can use active directory as this Microsoft example shows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907077(v=vs.85).aspx